# DirectoryIterator::getBasename vs DirectoryIterator::getFilename

Tags: php

Is there any difference between [`getBaseName`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getbasename.php) and [`getFilename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getfilename.php) when called with no arguments?

Comment: None. But if your question was "why did the API designer make two functions that do the same thing" then the answer is drugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is **no difference** except that `getBaseName` has a single parameter to cut suffix's of the file name. No significant difference. Although the `Base` suggest something more - I am quite sure it points to being able to cut things off at the end and nothing more.